# OpenWeatherMap API and the null Weather object

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit

I'm doing the weather app in Kotlin and I decided to use OpenWeatherMap API. I have problem with Weather object in my CurrentWeather class which is still null. I generated classes by library for Kotlin in Android Studio and Weather was a List. But there was a problem in logs - wrong type. So I changed type to the ArrayList and then type is ok, but in logs I see null for Weather. 
I've already used this in Java app and after change List to ArrayList API worked. I also checked API in Postman and there Weather works, so this is not an API error. What I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

Ok, I know few new things. This is not a problem api. There is problem with storing an ArrayList in Room database. I found working Weather data inside profiler logs. I have to find way, how to save this kind of data in Room storage.
CurrentWeather:

```
const val CURRENT_WEATHER_ID = 0

@Entity(tableName = "current_weather")
data class CurrentWeather(
@SerializedName("base")
val base: String,
@Embedded(prefix = "clouds_")
val clouds: Clouds,
@SerializedName("cod")
val cod: Int,
@Embedded(prefix = "coord_")
val coord: Coord,
@SerializedName("dt")
val dt: Int,
@SerializedName("id")
val id: Int,
@Embedded(prefix = "main_")
val main: Main,
@SerializedName("name")
val name: String,
@Embedded(prefix = "sys_")
val sys: Sys,
@SerializedName("visibility")
val visibility: Int,
@Expose
@Embedded(prefix = "weather_")
val weather: ArrayList<Weather>?,
@Embedded(prefix = "wind_")
val wind: Wind


) {
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
var idKey: Int = CURRENT_WEATHER_ID
}
```

Weather:

```
data class Weather(
@SerializedName("description")
val description: String,
@SerializedName("icon")
val icon: String,
@SerializedName("id")
val id: Int,
@SerializedName("main")
val main: String
)
```

API:

```
{
  "coord": {"lon": -122.08,"lat": 37.39},
  "weather": [
{
  "id": 800,
  "main": "Clear",
  "description": "clear sky",
  "icon": "01d"
}
],
"base": "stations",
"main": {
"temp": 296.71,
"pressure": 1013,
"humidity": 53,
"temp_min": 294.82,
"temp_max": 298.71
 },
 "visibility": 16093,
 "wind": {
 "speed": 1.5,
 "deg": 350
 },
 "clouds": {
 "all": 1
 },
 "dt": 1560350645,
 "sys": {
 "type": 1,
 "id": 5122,
 "message": 0.0139,
 "country": "US",
 "sunrise": 1560343627,
 "sunset": 1560396563
},
"timezone": -25200,
"id": 420006353,
"name": "Mountain View",
"cod": 200
}
```

Response in logs:

```
CurrentWeather(base=stations, clouds=Clouds(all=20), cod=200,coord=Coord(lat=34.05, lon=-118.24), dt=1564585552, id=5368361, main=Main(humidity=88, pressure=1015, temp=19.91, tempMax=21.67, tempMin=18.33), name=Los Angeles, sys=Sys(country=US, id=3514, message=0.0119, sunrise=1564578205, sunset=1564628107, type=1), visibility=8047, weather=null, wind=Wind(deg=160.0, speed=2.1))
```

Comment: please post your `Weather` class

Comment: I just pasted for you.

Comment: show the response from the server please

Comment: I pasted response from logs. You can check.